Where does it say that every disease has a spiritual source?
BH
Hi! Where does it say that every disease has a spiritual source? I heard that there were certain Tzaddikim who were able to see the spiritual source of sickness and could heal the person based on that.

Ramban Vayikra 26:11:

וכן היו הצדיקים עושים בזמן הנבואה גם כי יקרם עון שיחלו לא ידרשו ברופאים רק בנביאים
And so did the righteous ones act at the time when prophecy [existed], so that even if a mishap of iniquity overtook them, causing them sickness, they did not turn to the physicians, but only to the prophets...

He goes on to explain that back then physicians were mainly there to tell people what food is healthy, because people were on the level that all sickness was due to sin. Doing teshuva and attaining forgiveness and healing from Hashem was something the prophets helped with. Once people dropped below that level, they lost this privilege, and now we need medicine because a) Hashem has left us to the "happenings of the world", and b) Hashem has granted physicians permission to heal.

Why "only"?  Sad mistake.

@MauriceMizrahi see edit.

Where do you know your last paragraph from? Not a challenge. Just want to know

@Shababnik it is my summary of some of the points the Ramban makes in the next few lines of the long piece, which is linked

I think OP is asking more about the "mechanical" cause than reward and punishment.

@shmosel I'm not sure I follow. My answer doesn't need to presume reward and punishment. What's the "mechanical" cause of sickness?

I'm saying there's the reason something happens, which might be a warning, punishment, etc., and there's how it happens, e.g. a deficiency in some part of the soul with a corresponding effect on the body.

@shmosel and you are sure the question is about that? I personally try to avoid overly mechanical interpretations/explanations of Kabbalah but look forward to seeing an answer like that if someone submits it
